# Bash for loop testing two boolean expressions

Tags: bash

Below is a simple bash program. It takes file types as command line arguments and it queries the current directory and prints the files of the type specified.

I would like to be able to query two different file types and therefore need two boolean expressions to represent this.

Below is my code for querying just one file type

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in $(ls *$1); do
    echo $x;
done
```

Now what I would like to be able to do is (in pseudocode)

```
command line args fileName .sh .c

for x in (current directory files of *.sh) OR (in current directory files of *.c) do
     print .sh files
     print.c files
done
```

I've tried using || and I get syntax errors I can not find any evidence of being able to use || for two expressions in for loop.

I've tried using two nested for loops but they do not work and yield errors.

Is there any way I can accomplish this using the same for loop system.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no insistence, I am just interested if methods like this can be done using the for loop, the use of several do sections does make sense, I was not aware this was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
for extension in "$@"; do
    printf 'Files ending in %s:\n' "$extension"
    printf '%s\n' *"$extension"
done
```

Loop through all arguments passed to the script and print all files ending in each extension + a newline character.

Note that `printf` is a much more useful tool than `echo`, as it allows you to control the format of each thing is prints.

`ls` doesn't do anything useful either here; it is the shell which expands the `*` to the list of files matching the pattern.